# Performance testing in dart using test 0.12.15+3 lib

Tags: dart, performance-testing

We develop a computationally-intensive web app in Dart.
For the purposes of making sure our computations perform well across all platforms and browsers, we run benchmarks using the "test 0.12.15+3" package. However, we found out that in some cases, the difference in executing the same code differs by orders of magnitude. Below is the code that demonstrates the problem (sorting arrays using custom comparators).

I wonder if there is an explanation for the difference in time between the code being executed in chrome, and as test with choice of chrome as platform (pub run test -p chrome test/perf_test.dart) ?
 Is benchmarking via the test package a viable option, or should we look elsewhere?

```
import 'package:quiver/iterables.dart' as it;
void main(){
 Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
 int len = 1000000;//0000
 num v = 0;
 List ln0 = new List();
 for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  ln0.add(v++);
 //T1
 sw..reset()..start();
 ln0.sort((x,y) => x - y);
 sw..stop();
 print('Num Comparator take, mcs: ${sw.elapsedMicroseconds}');
 //T2
 List ln1= it.range(len).toList();
 sw..reset()..start();
 ln1.sort((x,y) => x - y);
 print('Suddenly, Num Comparator take, mcs: ${sw.elapsedMicroseconds}');

 //T3
 List li2 = it.range(len).map((numm)=>numm.toInt()).toList();
 sw..reset()..start();
 li2.sort((x,y)=>x - y);
 sw..stop();
 print('Int Comparator take, mcs: ${sw.elapsedMicroseconds}');

 List<String> items = new List(len);
 for(int i =0, len = items.length; i<len; i++){
  List tl = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','']..shuffle();
  items[i] = tl.join('');
 }

 Function _comparer = (String s1, String s2) {
  if (s1 == null && s2 == null) return 0;
  if (s1 == null) return 1;
  if (s2 == null) return -1;
  if (s1 == '' && s2 == '') return 0;
  if (s1 == '') return 1;
  if (s2 == '') return -1;
  return s1.compareTo(s2);
 };
 //T4
 List ls1 = new List.from(items);
 sw..reset()..start();
 ls1.sort((s1, s2) => s1.compareTo(s2));
 sw..stop();
 print('Standart String comparator take, mcs: ${sw.elapsedMicroseconds}');

 //T5
 List ls2 = new List.from(items);
 sw..reset()..start();
 ls2.sort(_comparer);
 sw..stop();
 print('String comparator(miss null,empty) take, mcs:    ${sw.elapsedMicroseconds}');
 }
```

Comment: here results ratio with dartium as base:
 *header |run as test in dartium|run as test in chrome|run in chrome browser | run in dartium browser         
*num         1,0 |    229,5 |       0,9 |1
*int          1,0 |     9,4    |      1,0 |1
*String  1,3 |    3,4     |      0,8 |1

Answer (score 2):

`test` is not supposed to be used for benchmarks. Use insted https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/benchmark_harness. It helps to cope with benchmark related requirements like warmup phase and number of runs to get more realistic results.

Comment: Thanks, You are right benchmark_harness will provide more precise results. But harness doesn't  have options for launching on different platforms and therefore we can't  avoid using test package for that. Launching  benchmark_harness from command line using test package with option: -p chrome produce almost same result ((. 
it looks like problem with test package.

Comment: Did you try `-j0` or `concurrency=0` ? https://github.com/dart-lang/test/blob/091cadbf0bdb6daf37cff1774723980714600552/doc/configuration.md#concurrency

Comment: With option j0, test doesn't  run at all, maybe you mean j1.
Just have tested with this option j1, it took  no effect  on results. Difference stays too big especially for num in test T2 (slower  in 200 times). 
also playing with j5 ...j10  and running only one test(for nums)  gives almost  same result. 
Thanks again for advice.  I expected what problem is solved with correct configuration  of test or pub run command but i don't see how.

Comment: Right `j1` :D. Perhaps creating an issue in the `dart-lang/test` Github repo with a link to this question might the attention of the right people.

Comment: For really valuable information on Dart benchmark and the benchmark_harness tool I recommend to read the article [Micro​benchmarking Dart](https://mrale.ph/blog/2021/01/21/microbenchmarking-dart-part-1.html), from the Dart developer [mraleph](https://github.com/mraleph). The article explains why the tool in its current state can give unreliable results, and shows a new version of the [benchmark_harness](https://github.com/mraleph/benchmark_harness) package it is developing and which I believe will replace the current one in the future. This information is generally valid for micro-benchmarking